# how to display html data stored in jinja2 variable

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I have a variable in my python flask application, which contains html data

```
html_data='<p> this data to be displayed </p>'
```

I have passed this variable in  `render_template(temp.html,data=html_data)`.

I need to display data variable in my temp.html, as HTML and not as string

I have tried `{{ data }}` it displays data as string and not HTML.

```
output: <p> this data to be displayed</p>'
```

I want the above data to be displayed as HTML.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try using the below:

```
{{ data | safe }}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think u can try this, so that it wouldn't be escaped.

```
{{ data | safe }}
```